# Python Dictionary: Simple division with massive DataFrame values in each indexes

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe, division, calculation

So I have a two Dictionaries which are composed with 10 of 3000 by 3000 Dataframe in each index(0~9). All the values in the Dataframe is int, and I just want to simply divide each values. The first loop below is only replacing index=column values into 0, and personally I do not think this loop is slowing the process. The second loop is the problem with run time (I believe) since there are too many data to compute. Please see the code below.

```
for a in range(10):
    for aa in range(len(dict_cat4[a])):
        dict_cat4[a].iloc[aa,aa] = 0
        dict_amt4[a].iloc[aa,aa] = 0
for b in range(10):
    temp_df3 = dict_amt4[b] / dict_cat4[b] 
    temp_df3.replace(np.nan,0.0,inplace=True)
    dict_div4[b] = temp_df3
```

One problem is that the process takes forever to compute this loop since the data set is very big. Is there a efficient way to convert my code into other loops? Now its been 60+ minutes and still computing. Please let me know! Thanks

-----------------edit------------------

Below is sample input and output of first loop

```
Output:dict_amt4[0]
       DNA      Cat2                                    ...     Func
       Item     A   B   C   D   E   F   F   H   I   J   ...     ZDF11  ZDF12  ZDF13  ZDF14  ZDF15   ZDF16   ZDF17  ZDF18   ZDF19   ZDF20
DNA   Item
Cat2  A         0   62  174 0   4   46  46  7   2   15  ...     4   17  45  1   2   0   0   0   0   0
      B         62  0   27  0   0   12  61  2   4   11  ...     6   9   14  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
      C         174 27  0   0   0   13  22  5   2   4   ...     0   2   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
      D         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
      E         4   0   0   0   0   10  57  33  4   5   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0
      F         46  12  13  0   10  0   4   5   0   0   ...     0   33  2   0   0   0   2   3   0   0
.............
```

And second loop is below

```
Input:dict_amt4[0]
       DNA      Cat2                                    ...     Func
       Item     A   B   C   D   E   F   F   H   I   J   ...     ZDF11  ZDF12  ZDF13  ZDF14  ZDF15   ZDF16   ZDF17  ZDF18   ZDF19   ZDF20
DNA   Item
Cat2  A         0   186 174 0   4   46  46  14  2   15  ...     4   17  45  1   2   0   0   0   0   0
      B         186 0   27  0   0   12  61  2   4   11  ...     6   9   14  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
      C         174 27  0   0   0   130 22  5   2   4   ...     0   2   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
      D         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
      E         4   0   0   0   0   10  57  33  4   5   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0
      F         46  12  13  0   10  0   4   5   0   0   ...     0   33  2   0   0   0   2   3   0   0
.............


Input:dict_cat4[0]
       DNA      Cat2                                    ...     Func
       Item     A   B   C   D   E   F   F   H   I   J   ...     ZDF11  ZDF12  ZDF13  ZDF14  ZDF15   ZDF16   ZDF17  ZDF18   ZDF19   ZDF20
DNA   Item
Cat2  A         0   62  174 0   4   46  46  7   2   15  ...     4   17  45  1   2   0   0   0   0   0
      B         62  0   27  0   0   12  61  2   4   11  ...     6   9   14  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
      C         174 27  0   0   0   13  22  5   2   4   ...     0   2   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
      D         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
      E         4   0   0   0   0   10  57  33  4   5   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0
      F         46  12  13  0   10  0   4   5   0   0   ...     0   33  2   0   0   0   2   3   0   0
.............


Output:dict_div4[0]
       DNA      Cat2                                    ...     Func
       Item     A   B   C   D   E   F   F   H   I   J   ...     ZDF11  ZDF12  ZDF13  ZDF14  ZDF15   ZDF16   ZDF17  ZDF18   ZDF19   ZDF20
DNA   Item
Cat2  A         0   3   1   0   1   1   1   2   1   1   ...     1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
      B         3   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   ...     1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
      C         1   1   0   0   0   10  1   1   1   1   ...     0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
      D         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
      E         1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
      F         1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   ...     0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
.............
```

I just made a sample data by hand, so please disregard typo. As you can see the first loop is just converting a value that dict_cat4[0].iloc[i,i] = 0. Second loop is dividing all the value from dict_amt[0] to dict_cat[0]. Hope it makes more sense.

Comment: Having a dict of DataFrames feels odd.   Perhaps you can merge the DataFrames into one and apply the computation on appropriate columns.

Comment: I want to keep the dict format if possible.

Comment: The question is why do you need the dict format?  Just about anything you can do with a dict you can accomplish with a single DataFrame.

Comment: just wondering, is this really a dictionary or just a list of dataframe? similarly, the dataframes are pandas?